# The "right" way to define a custom Encoding format?

Tags: export, import

I have implemented an `Import|Export` format for [xz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) that behaves like gzip and other encoding formats:

```
Import["some.ext.gz"]
Import["some.ext.xz"]
```

But I think I did it in a really roundabout way, is there a more straightforward way than adding `DownValues` for all these things:

```
ImportExport`EncodingsDump`rundecoder["XZ", infile_String, outfile_String, opts___]
ImportExport`EncodingsDump`runencoder["XZ", infile_String, outfile_String, opts___]
FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATMATRIX["XZ"] (* $ /mma.SE bug *)
ImportExport`EncodingsDump`InstallCoderQ["XZ"]
ImportExport`EncodingsDump`CreateShortName[infile_ /; StringMatchQ[infile, "*.xz"]]
AppendTo[FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATS, "XZ"]
```

Together with:

```
ImportExport`RegisterImport["XZ", ImportXZ,
   "BinaryFormat"->True,
   "Extensions"->{"*.xz"},
   "Encoding"->True,
   "AvailableElements"->{_String},
   "FunctionChannels"->{"FileNames"}]
 (* Similar for Export *)
```

What's the best way to do this?